# Azure durable function for bulk insert toward Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-durable-functions

my Azure's serverless architecture is composed from some producers, a service bus, un azure function and a Postgres DB (see the below picture).

The Postgres DB is a legacy requirement, I cannot change it.

The following is the operations flow:

1. The producers send a message with a temporal frequency towards service bus (about 9000 messagges/minute). Every producers sends a single message.
2. The azure functions consumes the message and insert a row into the Postgres DB

In order to avoid a strong load of DB and open a lot of connections I would to aggregate the messages into the function and inset them by bulk insert. 
Could I work well with a durable function (entity function)?

Can you help me please? Best Regards

[image]

Comment: Each function invocation should receive a batch of messages anyway already and not being called per single message https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/15#issuecomment-518794343

Comment: Great, can I configure it?

Comment: what do you need to configure?

Comment: The size of batch of messages. For example an amount of bytes or the messages number

Comment: Looking at the PR, I would say: yes. but not sure how exactly. Might be worth to open a issue in the github repo. default seems to be 1000: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/pull/39/files#diff-14c7bafaa5a77aa0227141e443bff6a1R37

Comment: got it to work. see my answer below

Comment: @silent thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it to work as discussed in the comments. You don't need a durable function but you should receive (and then write) messages in batches from the Service Bus. Here is a batching example:

```
[FunctionName("QueueTriggeredFunction")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("demofunctionqueue", Connection = "queueconstring")]string[] myQueueItems, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("Received messages {count}", myQueueItems.Length);
    foreach (var myQueueItem in myQueueItems)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

`host.json` to set the maximum number of messages per batch

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "batchOptions": {
        "maxMessageCount": 200
      },
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: He is using consumption plan. So, even if you limit the messages per batch on the function's instance, you will not limit the number of instances that can scale up on his function app. So he would have 10 instances of the function app consuming 1-2 messages each.

Comment: Fair enough, I edited the host.json above to add the config switch for max concurrency

Comment: maxConcurrentCalls does not work with Consumption plan. Please read my comments on my answer.

Comment: According to this one it should work? https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2667#issuecomment-456612622

Comment: @silent thanks, i will try your solution. So, with maxMessageCount can I define the batch size, and with "maxConcurrentCalls" can i set the max numbers of azure functions runs concurrently. Is it right?

Comment: yes, should be like that. If you still see multiple instances being spawned, you might need to also set WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT as suggested by @HugoBarona

Comment: where I can set WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT ?

Comment: @MichelFoucault in the app settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings

Comment: @silent I've not found the options "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "batchOptions": {
        "maxMessageCount": 200
      },
The reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json reports: "aggregator": {
        "batchSize": 1000,
        "flushTimeout": "00:00:30"
    }

Comment: @MichelFoucault they are currently missing on that doc page. Thats why I added a complete sample above in my answer

Comment: @silent I tried with a Node.js fuctions, I have just readed that in C# the features is provided by WebJobs SDK. Do you know something similar for Node.js?

Comment: No sorry, I can’t say much to node.js functions

Answer (score 1):

I would consider Durable Functions just in case if you have multiple steps, so then you can build your workflow using Durable Functions. In your case, what I would do is to play around with the *maxConcurrentCalls* parameter on your hosts.json file, so you can then set an acceptable value for concurrent calls for your DB. Please reference [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/host.json-(v2)) to get more info.

Comment: Hi Hugo, thanks for you reponse. Does "maxConcurrentCalls" limits the number of concurrent calls towards consumers (Azure function)?

Comment: @MichelFoucault in that case you should use the configuration setting *WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT*. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings)